# Absolute fixed div with horizontal content CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using Bootstrap in my website. And i need a div at right bottom of page over the body content, where All 4 post will be horizontal. Something like that

I am adding these 4 post's with JQuery one by one after clicking on button here is the line

```
$('#form_container').append('<div class="rows"> <input type="hidden" value="'+response.data.post_id+'"> <a href="#" class="remove-title">X</a> <img src="'+response.data.post_thumb+'"/> <br> '+response.data.post_title+' </input></div>');
```

This is `HTML Form` where these input's add with JQuery.

```
<div id="form-div">
 <form id="form_container" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>final" method="POST">
  <button type="button" class="div-close"><span aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:20px">&times;</span></button>

   <!–– Here is Added 4 input's with JQuery ––>

  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Compare">
 </form>
</div>
```

**How to create`<div id="form-div">` at right bottom with `horizontal` post's to look good?**

I need same copy as in picture.

Here is JSFIddle which i trying [JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/L7ybnLz1/8/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, may be this will help you.
Try now , i have edited my code to show this div always at bottom

```css
#form-div{
 position:fixed;
 float:left;
  margin-bottom:0px;
  padding-bottom:0px;
  bottom:0;
  
}
.div-close{
 float:right;
}
.remove-title{
  float:right;
}
#form_container{
 background:#fff;
 width:500px;
 height:200px;
 border:2px solid #000; 
 position:relative;
  padding:15px;
    margin:0;
}

.rows{
  float: left; /* ADD THIS */
  margin-right: 5px; /* AND LIKELY THIS ETC */
  width:75px;
  height:100px;
  text-align:center;
  font-weight:bold;
  border: 3px solid #ddd;
}
.rows a{
 margin-top:0px;
 padding-top:0px;
 float:right;
}
#form_container img {
 width:75px;
 height:100px;
}
.compare{
 width: 81px;
float: none;
background: red;
margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="jumbotron text-center">
  <h1>My First Bootstrap Page</h1>
  <p>Resize this responsive page to see the effect!</p> 
</div>
  
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h3>Column 1</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h3>Column 2</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h3>Column 3</h3>        
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="form-div">
<form id="form_container" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>final" method="POST">
<button type="button" class="div-close"><span aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:20px">&times;</span></button>

<div class="rows"><input type="hidden" value="1"><a href="#" class="remove-title">X</a><img src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/1.jpg"/> <br> Picture 1 </input></div>

<div class="rows"><input type="hidden" value="2"><a href="#" class="remove-title">X</a><img src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/2.jpg"/> <br> Picture 2 </input></div>

<div class="rows"><input type="hidden" value="3"><a href="#" class="remove-title">X</a><img src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/3.jpg"/> <br> Picture 3 </input></div>

<div class="rows"><input type="hidden" value="4"><a href="#" class="remove-title">X</a><img src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/4.jpg"/> <br> Picture 4 </input></div>


<div style="clear:both;">
</div>
<input type="submit" class="compare" name="submit" value="Compare">
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This div show in middle. need at right bottom please fix this

Comment: try now, i have edited my code, now this div will always appear at bottom

Comment: Still not. I think need both fixed and absolute properties in css

Answer (score 1):

Just float your `.rows` left...

```
.rows{
  float: left; /* ADD THIS */
  margin-right: 5px; /* AND LIKELY THIS ETC */
  width:75px;
  height:100px;
  text-align:center;
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/8yqev3Ly/

Something like this maybe. It gets relatively responsive out of the box with flexbox.

```
<div class="flexcontainer">
  <article>
    <span>X</span>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x125">
    <label>
      Samsung mobile phone;
    </label>
  </article>

    <article>
      <span>X</span>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x125">
      <label>
        Samsung mobile phone;
      </label>
  </article>

    <article>
      <span>X</span>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x125">
      <label>
        Samsung mobile phone;
      </label>
  </article>

    <article>
      <span>X</span>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x125">
      <label>
        Samsung mobile phone;
      </label>
    </article>
  <button>Compare!</button>
  </div>
```

css

```
.flexcontainer{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  justify-content:space-around;
   padding:5px;
  border:2px solid black;
}
.box{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;

  padding:5px;
  border:2px solid black;
}
article{

  display:flex;
  flex:1;
  position:relative;
  border:1px solid gray;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  flex-direction:column;
  margin:5px;
}
img{
  margin:15px;

}
button{
 margin-top:auto;
 height:20px;
}

span{
  margin-left:auto;
}
```